# Install vim plugin on Ubuntu docker image

Tags: python, docker, vim, root

I'm trying to install the [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe) vim plugin on a linux docker image.

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# minimal nix stuff ...
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN apt-get install vim -y
RUN apt-get install curl -y

# pathogen stuff ...
RUN mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload
RUN mkdir -p ~/.vim/bundle
RUN curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim

# for cmake annoying questions ...
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# dependencies ...
RUN apt install build-essential cmake vim-nox python3-dev -y

# vim stuff ...
RUN echo "execute pathogen#infect()"  > ~/.vimrc
RUN echo "syntax on"                 >> ~/.vimrc
RUN echo "filetype plugin indent on" >> ~/.vimrc
RUN echo "color evening"             >> ~/.vimrc
RUN echo "set number"                >> ~/.vimrc
RUN echo "set tabstop=4"             >> ~/.vimrc
RUN echo "set shiftwidth=4"          >> ~/.vimrc
RUN echo "set expandtab"             >> ~/.vimrc

# ycm stuff ...
RUN cd ~/.vim/bundle && git clone https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe.git
RUN cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe && git submodule update --init --recursive
```

The above steps are fine, but when I try to do the final step:

```
RUN python3 ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/install.py
```

I get the following error:

```
 => ERROR [20/20] RUN python3 ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/install.py                                      0.4s
------
 > [20/20] RUN python3 ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/install.py:
#23 0.377 This script should not be run with root privileges.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c python3 ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/install.py]: exit code: 1
```

The docker command I use to run the `Dockerfile` above is:

```
docker build --tag host --file Dockerfile .
```

Comment: Are you ok with running this command `sudo apt-get update` ?

Answer (score 0):

According to this link, https://installati.one/ubuntu/22.04/vim-youcompleteme/, I would add this line `apt-get -y install vim-youcompleteme`

So the Docker file would start with:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# minimal nix stuff ...
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN apt-get install vim -y
RUN apt-get install curl -y
# new line I am suggesting.
RUN apt-get -y install vim-youcompleteme
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me - doesn't recognize `:YcmRestartServer` for example

Comment: @OrenIshShalom  Could you try going into ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/ and running `python install.py`.  Just troubleshooting here.

Answer (score 0):

a little off topic, but I advise you not to use so many RUN's, read
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

example:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git vim curl && apt-get clean
```

this will make the image lighter

Comment: Yes, you're right - the thing is, since I try so many times to get this to work, the multiple `RUN` commands enable cached layers which make the docker build much (much) faster. If one has a single `RUN` command and it fails then NO caching exists ...